# The $K_0$ mapping of an automorphism induced by a derivation

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a unital $C^*$-Algebra and let $\delta: \mathfrak{A} \rightarrow \mathfrak{A}$ be a linear map that is not constantly zero and satisfies, for every $A, B\in\mathfrak{A}$, $\delta(AB) = \delta(A)B + A\delta(B)$. It is proved [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61993-9) by **Sakai** that $\delta$ (called **derivation**) is always coutinuous. Then define:

$$
e^{\delta}(A) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\delta^n(A)}{n!}
$$

where $\delta^0(A) = A$ for each $A\in\mathfrak{A}$. For every $A, B\in\mathfrak{A}$, since one can prove that for each $N > 0$, $\delta^N(AB) = \sum_{i\leq N}\binom{N}{i}\delta^i(A)\delta^{N-i}(B)$, one can check that $e^{\delta}$ is an endormophism. Also notice that for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, we have $\lambda\delta$ defined by $(\lambda\delta)(A) = \lambda\delta(A)$ is also a derivation and given $\lambda, \mu\in\mathbb{C}$, one can show $e^{\lambda\delta}e^{\mu\delta}(A) = e^{\mu\delta}e^{\lambda\delta}(A) = e^{(\lambda+\mu)\delta}(A)$ (the same way we prove the equation of $\delta^N(AB)$). Hence $e^{\delta}$ is an automorphism with inverse $e^{-\delta}$.

My question is: is it true that, because for each $A\in\mathfrak{A}$, $e^{\delta}(A)$ is homotopic to $0$ through the path $e^{t\delta}(A)$ where $t\in[0, 1]$, then, in the context of $K$-theory, $K_0(e^{\delta})$ is the zero mapping from $K_0(\mathfrak{A})$ to $K_0(\mathfrak{A})$? I believe the path $[0, 1]\rightarrow\mathfrak{A}, t\mapsto e^{t\delta}(A)$ is continuous for each $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ because $\delta$ is bounded, but find it hard for me to believe the conclusion is true. **Moreover, anyone who can provide any more info about the automorphism $e^{\delta}$ where $\delta$ is a derivation will be highly appreciated**. Definitions you may need for $K$-theory can be found on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-theory).

Comment: When cross-posting on the stackexchange network, please always include links to the posts on the other sites. Aweygan now essentially repeated Jamie Gabe's comment, which could have been easily avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and I will be more careful in the next post.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.  First, one normally defines $\delta^0(A)$ to be $A$ for all $A\in\mathfrak A$.  This is consistent with the rest of your claims in the first paragraph.

Secondly, $e^\delta(A)$ is not homotopic to $0$ through the path $(e^{t\delta}(A))_{t\in[0,1]}$, but instead this path connects $e^\delta(A)$ to $A$.  Because of this, the automorphism $e^\delta$ induces **the identity map** on $K_0(\mathfrak A)$.  This is because for every projection $P\in M_n(\mathfrak A)$, $P$ is homotopic to $e^{\delta}(P)$ (writing $e^\delta$ for its matrix expansion, excuse my abuse of notation), hence the two projections give the same $K$-theory class and we have
$$(e^\delta)_*[P]_0=[e^\delta(P)]_0=[P]_0=\operatorname{Id}_{K_0(\mathfrak A)}[P]_0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. It is my mistake not checking my posts so that I could have not made the mistake.